# C Programming "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when using free()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free, coredump

I'm trying to create a two dimensional array but when i use free at the end of my program i always get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. The sleep function is only used because i wanted to see if it crashes after creating the array or later, and the program crashes as soon as i use free(array)

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <unistd.h>


void check(int number)
{
    if(number < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "You cannot use a value below zero!\n");
    }
}


int create_array(int **array, int size)
{
    array = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("Successfully created the array!\n");
    printf("The size of the array is %d * %d = %d", size, size, sizeof(array) / sizeof(int));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int main(void)
{
    int N;
    printf("Please enter a value for N: ");
    scanf("%d", & N);
    check(N);

    int R;
    printf("Please enter a value for R: ");
    scanf("%d", & R);
    check(R);

    int **array;
    create_array(array, N);
    sleep(1);
    free(array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: A better way of determining *where* it was crashing would be to step teh code in a debugger.  You can also use a debugger to see that the pointer returned by `malloc()` is not the same value as that you pass to `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are only modifying a local copy of `array` in `create_array()` function. In order to be able to modify the pointer `array` in main(), you need to pass a pointer to it (i.e. the function needs to receive a `int***`).

More simply, you can *return* the `array` from the function and *assign* it to the `array` in main() and you wouldn't need to pass the first argument.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you are creating dynamic array but you are not returning the reference of that array, thats why you are failing to free it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `create_array()` as follows:

```
int **array;
create_array( &array, N);
```

Then define it as:

```
int create_array(int*** array, int size)
{
    *array = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        (*array)[i] = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("Successfully created the array!\n");
    printf("The size of the array is %d * %d = %d", size, size, sizeof(array) / sizeof(int));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You will still have a memory leak however since you are only freeing `array` and not freeing `array[0]` to `array[N-1]`.  It would be safer to create a corresponding `destroy_array()` function.